# How to get the cumulative distribution function?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-functions

I did 1000 experiments on the same thing. I want to get a graph of its cumulative
distribution function. But if I simply draw, there will be 1000 points. Can I get an average value every 50 trials and then draw a graph of 10 points? Does that make sense?...

I checked the definition of cumulative distribution function `F(a)=P(x<=a)` on Wikipedia. Does this mean that the value of this function is always greater than 0?

Comment: Try [an EDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function).

Comment: However, similar experiments in other papers use CDF. The paper said that he had done 1,000 experiments, but there were only 20 points on the picture. Is it reasonable to get an average of the 50 experiments?